# Get array of images from JS to Django template

Tags: javascript, django

I want to show random images every time someone enters my art gallery or on refresh and change the images on my art gallery every 30 seconds.
I have everything set up correctly in Django.
In JS I have created a list of jpeg files.
I want to pick a random picture. I am not sure how to use the Django syntax {% %} in JS nor do I know if it is possible. There is some [code](https://gist.github.com/corradomatt/b7cce3c907fc5cbe85e8) I found and it does something like this:

```js
//Add your images, we'll set the path in the next step
    var images = ['banner-1.jpg', 'banner-2.jpg', 'banner-3.jpg', 'banner-4.jpg];
    
//Build the img, then do a bit of maths to randomize load and append to a div. Add a touch off css to fade them badboys in all sexy like.
    $('<img class=" class="fade-in" src="images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">').appendTo('#banner-load');
</script>
```

However, I would like use the Django syntax or something similar so I don't have to specify the path to the images. Nonetheless, I am also looking for other solutions, so I don't really need to use the Django syntax.

Also, is there a way to tie this to a timer that will continue to show random pictures for my art gallery?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you storing your images? If they are just stored in your static directory you can do this all with javascript - if you created (for example) an `Image` model and are keeping your images in a table, you can leverage the django templating language.

Comment: I saved them in the images directory which is in the static directory. Is there a different way to solve this without using the Django syntax? I want to save me the trouble to manually type everything lol

Answer (score 0):

In your template you can "fill" the path part with the `static` template tag:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'banner-1.jpg' %}" alt="My image">
```

About the list of images, you can pass that list from the view [context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data)

For the timer you need javascript.

You can read more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/